# Wbadmin backup failed due to a file system limitation

Tags: windows, command-line, backup, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to setup and learn the Wbadmin command line prompts for making my own backups. I'm created a test on Server 2008 R2 in VMWare, I've created a separate B: drive for backups. I'm trying to target specific files, and I've created 6 testFile# .txt files in the C drive under the !Test folder.

The command that I've used is:

```
wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:\\localhost\NetworkShare -include:C:\!Test\testFile*
```

The process starts, but ends up crashing. Screenshot attached below. The logs for both the backup and the error are blank. The main error message is:

```
There was a failure in updating the backup for deleted items.
The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation
```

What am I doing wrong? B: was formatted to NTFS, and I've followed the instructions exactly.

[image]

Comment: pretty sure -include must be a volume and that is does not support wildcards

Comment: Without more detail as to why, I don't see how that is helpful. According the Microsoft documentation: technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742130(v=ws.11).aspx, wildcards are accepted in the include. Also, the "include" operation accepts file, folders, and volumes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research, I found the cause of the error message. The proplem came from within the Virtual Machine itself. The VM or the Operating System was not configured, so Wbadmin would not accept the destination of //localhost/NetworkShare

When I tried backing up to a real network drive, everything worked as planned. The * wildcard, hoping to grab only the 6 testFiles numbered 1-6, worked correctly. However in real practice listing each individual file name after a comma: , will probably be more useful for others. Here is the command that worked:

```
wbadmin start backup -backuptarget:\\(IP address of network)\Public -inlcude:C:\!Test\testFile*
```

Here was the log report:

```
    Backed up C:\
Backed up C:\!Test\
Backed up C:\!Test\testFile1.txt
Backed up C:\!Test\testFile2.txt
Backed up C:\!Test\testFile3.txt
Backed up C:\!Test\testFile4.txt
Backed up C:\!Test\testFile5.txt
Backed up C:\!Test\testFile6.txt
```

I hope this helps someone else